# Appending logs to flashlog.txt?

Tags: flash, logging, flex3

I have few questions regarding flex logging...
i. how do i append logs in existing flashlog.txt???
ii.can we append timestamp to name of flashlog.txt??eg.flashlog_2/25/2010_14:07:32.974.txt
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

i. There is the undocumented option
PolicyFileLogAppend = 1|0

Check out this great site with all undocumented options:
http://jpauclair.net/2010/02/10/mmcfg-treasure/

ii. This one is a bit harder to implement.
First of all the flash logging is crap. I would totally use a proper logging framework and send the data to the server, where you have all the freedom to do with it what you want.
Formerly there was the option TraceOutputFileName, which would do exactly what you want, but it seems not to be suppeorted in newer flashplayers anymore.
For that pourpose and if it all has to be on the client side, I would use a client side scrpt (bash, bat, a local flash move with "local filesystem" rights, a ria, whatever) and watch the file for changes (can be done in any OS). Mybe a final trace with some magic word that conatins the name of the target file (like trace("tracecomplete:flashlog_2/25/2010_14:07:32.974.txt")). The script watches the log file, if any change occurs, it looks for that line and if it finds it, it copies the file to the specified location and deletes it.
But do yourself a favour and if there is any chance to be able to do taht, log it to the net and let the server do the rest.